# Filter on hybrid property evaluates to "where false"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I set up a mapping...

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

Base = declarative_base()

class Chap(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'chap'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tophats = Column(Integer)
    exclamation = Column(String)

    @hybrid_property
    def hat_brag(self):
        return "I have "+str(self.tophats)+" tophats!"

    @hybrid_property
    def cold_complain(self):
        return self.exclamation+", it's cold!"
```

...and I created a chap.

```
>>>c1 = Chap(tophats=5, exclamation="Blimey")
```

Now I want to query this chap based on how he complains about the weather:

```
>>>print(Session().query(Chap).filter(Chap.cold_complain == "Blimey, it's cold!"))
SELECT chap.id AS chap_id, chap.tophats AS chap_tophats, chap.gloves AS chap_gloves, chap.exclamation AS chap_exclamation 
FROM chap 
WHERE chap.exclamation || :exclamation_1 = :param_1
```

That SQL code looks right, but now I want to query him on another hybrid_property, one that contains an `int` converted to a `str`...

```
>>>print(Session().query(Chap).filter(Chap.hat_brag == "I have 5 tophats!"))
SELECT chap.id AS chap_id, chap.tophats AS chap_tophats, chap.exclamation AS chap_exclamation 
FROM chap 
WHERE false
```

WHERE false. That doesn't look like the right query! Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a query, SQLAlchemy will use the getter method of a hybrid property without a dedicated [`@...expression()` method](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_property.expression) to produce the necessary SQL objects used for a query. The getter method is bound to the *class*, not an instance, so `self` in this scenario will reference your `Chap` class.

For your `cold_complain` property, that means `Chap.exclamation + ", it's cold!"` is returned, resulting in a `chap.exclamation || :exclamation_1` SQL expression; the `+` translated to the SQL concatenation operator.

But for your `hat_brag` property returns a string; the expression executed is really `"I have "+str(Chap.tophats)+" tophats!"`, which becomes `'I have Chap.tophats tophats!'`:

```
>>> "I have "+str(Chap.tophats)+" tophats!"
'I have Chap.tophats tophats!'
```

That's a fixed, static string. Next, this is made part of your filter, with `== "I have 5 tophats!"`. These two static string values are not equal:

```
>>> "I have "+str(Chap.tophats)+" tophats!" == "I have 5 tophats!"
False
```

So that's what is being used in the SQL query sent to the database.

What you want to do here instead is to use the [`expression()` option](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_property.expression) and define a SQL-friendly version of your query:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import cast

class Chap(Base):
    # ...

    @hybrid_property
    def hat_brag(self):
        return "I have "+str(self.tophats)+" tophats!"

    @hat_brag.expression
    def hat_brag(cls):
        return "I have " + cast(cls.tophats, String) + " tophats!"
```

Now the `expression` method is used for queries, and the original function on instances, in Python:

```
>>> c1.hat_brag
'I have 5 tophats!'
>>> print(Session().query(Chap).filter(Chap.hat_brag == "I have 5 tophats!"))
SELECT chap.id AS chap_id, chap.tophats AS chap_tophats, chap.exclamation AS chap_exclamation
FROM chap
WHERE :param_1 || CAST(chap.tophats AS VARCHAR) || :param_2 = :param_3
```

Comment: Interesting, so `c1hat_brag` can be 2 completely different things depending on where you're accessing it from. Also, you're then forced to write out manyof your  `@property`s twice. I wonder if this is all intentional.

Comment: @timwiz: yes, it is very much intentional. That's why it is a *hybrid* property, it is useful in multiple contexts (attribute, SQL expresson, and if you support a setter, then as a writable attribute, and the bulk update SQL expression), but you may need to tailor it to those contexts if you can't find a spelling that works in all.

Comment: Maybe the answer is in your comment, but why would you want `c1.hat_brag` to be `"I have ___ tophats!"` if accessed through python and `"Look at all ___ of my tophats!"` if accessed through the db? Maybe there's a good example, but it seems that you'd *always* want an object's attribute to be the same no matter where it's accessed from. @Martijn Pieters

Comment: @timwiz: a SQL expression is not the same thing as a Python value. SQLAlchemy does it’s best to have Python expressions mimic SQL syntax but that’s not always feasible; like the `str()` call in your example. So the `expression` option lets you build the SQL expression version where the Python expression to produce a Python value doesn’t directly translate (from `str()` to a `CAST` in this case).

Comment: @timwiz: this isn’t about using a different expression on the database side here, it’s about being able to use your property just like the column definitions on a model, both in context of a Python instance modelling the database data and when using the “column” in a SQL expression when querying.

Comment: That's what I thought. That's what I was wondering: if the ability to set one attribute as two different things depending on the access medium was intentional. Seems like instead it's just a weird side effect of sqlalchemy's solution to the problem.

Comment: @timwiz: it is due to SQLAlchemy doing its best to bridge two very different languages, and being mature enough to know that it can't do so for all possible scenarios.